# driver.switchTo().alert(); is throwing null pointer exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

facing it Only with edge 106,107,108 and the latest driver.
and I'm using selenium 3.4.0

NullPointerException Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getWindowHandle(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2174fa6c.CGLIB$getWindowHandle
$63() at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2174fa6c$$FastClassByCGLIB
$$d8f722da.invoke() at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at *************************************** at
org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2174fa6c.getWindowHandle()

**the same is working for all other browsers, it started with the edge 106 release, and it is coming intermittently.**
If required furthur info please comment.

facing it only with edge drivers 106,107,108 and the latest.
and I'm using selenium 3.4.0

Comment: Do you mean the same code works correctly on other browsers?

Comment: Yes the same is working for all other browsers, it started with edge 106 release, and it is coming intermittently.

Comment: Please add this inside the question. This is very important detail.

Comment: Here's Selenium 4.6.0 and EdgeDriver 107.0.1418.42. `driver.switchTo().alert()` didn't throw any exception. I would suggest updating to the latest version of Selenium

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace for further analysis. as this is Nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

Please try also this solution:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Then you can `accept(),dismiss(), sendkeys(), or getText()` using alert`.`

Comment: I've tried this, but no luck.